# SSRS 2008R2: Visual Studio 2008 and “2008” and “2010” schemas

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 (including Business Intelligence Development Studio). I have the following two questions:

1. I open the Business Intelligence Development Studio (Visual Studio 2008 appears as the result). I create a new Report Server project (specifying "2008R2" as TargetServerVersion). In the project I create a Report with some, say, table control. 
   Then I look into the RDL file generated and see the following:
   *http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2008**/01/reportdefinition*

The question is: can I somehow have the Studio to generate “2010” in the RDL file instead of the “2008”? Something like the following:

*xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2010**/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2010**/01/reportdefinition*

2. The second question is the following. I have an RDL file provided by other developer who implemented it in Report Builder 3.0 SQL Server 2008 R2. The RDL file uses “2010” schema:

*xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2010**/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/**2010**/01/reportdefinition*

I have added the file into my project (the one I described above in (1)). It seems everything works OK – I mean my Visual Studio 2008 does not appear any troubles while working with the RDL file (it uses “2010”, let me remind).

Can I be sure there will be no problems with this RDL included into my project. I mean – will not I meet a problem like the following: when I try to make some change in the report (move a control, add a control, modify a control – whatever) – the operation fails because of the “2010” schema in the RDL file> Or any other problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same scenario. I'd love to know how my fellow dev created the 2010 schema rdl file even though they apparently have the same tooling installed as me. I have been unable to find any way to create 2010 schema files other than copy-pasting theirs. SSRS is such a dog's dinner to work with.

Answer (score 2):

the namespaces are set when the report is first created.  So the simplest answer is to edit the template report file which can be found in the dir below  (for VS2013)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject
```

If you are using a earlier version of Visual Studio the root folder will be different.  Just chose the right directory for you version

[image]

NOTE:  you can also add your own templates in this folder that will appear in the add new item dialog.  Great if you want to prepare headers/footers and standard params...

[image]

Comment: Useful info, thanks. Though doesn't answer the bit about compatibility with server versions. Also I don't know where you'd find a template for the 2010 schema .rdl, as these have a substantially different xml structure, there must be one somewhere!